# Pyqt Pass Variable to QDialog Class

Tags: python, pyqt, qgis

I have developed a QGIS plugin using Pyqt.  I now have a need within this plugin to have a QDialog popup have its fields populated with data from our database.

My problem is how to pass a variable (in this case it might be a table and row reference) into a class and have it used by the static method.

If I print a passed in variable from within the class it will return the variable in addition to None??  If I take the same variable and try and populate a qplaintextedit it won't work because its complaining of being type 'None'.

Here is some test code I'm trying out just to get the concept down...

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import pdb

class mydi(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, pass_var, parent=None):
        super(mydi, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.pass_var = pass_var

        print pass_var
        self.txt_comments = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.txt_comments.appendPlainText(pass_var)
        layout.addWidget(self.txt_comments)

        self.buttons = QDialogButtonBox(
        QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel,
        Qt.Horizontal, self)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttons)

        self.buttons.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.buttons.rejected.connect(self.reject)

    def something(self):
        return self.somevar

    def comments(self):
        return self.txt_comments.toPlainText()


    @staticmethod
    def getData(parent=None):
        dialog = mydi(None)
        dialog.exec_()

        return (dialog.comments())

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    pass_in_var = "test"
    dia = mydi(pass_in_var)

    data = dia.getData()
    print data
```

Comment: I suggest you look more carefully at what you're passing to `getData`, and what you're passing to `mydi`. It also makes no sense to create an instance of `mydi` **and** call `getData` as well.

Comment: thank you so much.  you are 100% correct.  I did originally try just using the getdata staticmethod call originally but kept getting an error for having a non-default coming after a default.  The error was so literal I honestly didn't connect the dots.  I have now altered the getData(pass_var,parent=None) and it works as originally intended when I call such as: flub,snub = midi.getData(pass_in_var). no need to create an instance of mydi class first.